# Mac hard drive showing wrong size

Tags: mac, hard-drive

I have a 500GB Mac internal hard drive and have all my music files on there.

I recently made a New User because I was having trouble with a soundcard and was advised to try the card's driver install on a new user, so I created a new user. The driver still did not install.

So I went back to my old user account.

To my shock, my hard drive was now only 249GB capacity.

I eventually deleted the other User, but still, the drive is only 249GB and not 500GB

How can I get my disk space back?

```
News-MBP:~ newuser$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         249.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Mac HD                  171.5 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
```

Mac is on High Sierra

MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)

I tried a few things from off Google, like Spotlite and adding the hard drive and removing again, deleted Time Machine snapshots.

But that did nothing.

I don't understand how adding a user can take away half my drive space...

[image: System Info]

[image: Drive Info]

[image: Get Info]

[image: Hardware info]

[image: No NVMExpress]

[image: Storage]

Comment: Is your Music still there? And, primarily, are you sure there should be a 500 GB disk installed?

Comment: You do not have a drive with 500 capacity - your changes to the software didn’t change the hardware.

Comment: hmmm. the music was still there yes.

Comment: Could of sworn it was a 500GB drive though.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd, 4th, and 6th screenshots include the model number of the SSD - CT250MX500SSD1. A quick web search shows this to be a [Crucial 250GB SATA SSD](https://www.crucial.com/ssd/mx500/ct250mx500ssd1).

It was never a 500GB.

Answer (score 0):

It's rare the system would mis-characterize storage, and more common that it got intentionally shrunk if you physically have 500 but a disk is presented as 256. Can you make sure the About This Mac and System Information panes all show the 500 capacity?

[image: Storage]

[image: System Information NVMExpress]

As you can see in the NVME storage image, the system knows the serial number of the attached storage, so you could call Apple to validate you still have the drive that was installed from the factory if you somehow think you purchased one with 512 storage instead of 256.

Comment: They dont either no. and theres no way that it was done intentionally. 

(Added images to main Post)

Comment: You do not have a 512 GB drive

Comment: Its ok, cant remember weather it was a 250GB or 500GB now... BUT also i have files that went missing... so sumthing happened. Sumhow. Eitherway thanks for your help guys, i appreacitate it.